# Do global variable constructors/destructors need thread protection?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

If I have a class whose sole purpose is to have global `static` instances (to ensure the code in it's constructor is run before `main`) and it uses a class `static` variable, does access to this variable need to be protected via mutex?

An example will help:

```
class WinSock
{
public:
  WinSock()
  {
    if(!(inst++))
      //winsock init
  }
  ~WinSock()
  {
    if(!--inst)
      //winsock deactivate
  }
private:
  static int inst = 0;
}
static WinSock unusedWinSockVar;
```

This is all in a header that is included by any file using winsock. Does access to `inst` need to be protected, or is it impossible for this code to be run from multiple threads since threads will be created only once `main` runs and destroyed before `main` returns?

Comment: I don't see `inst` being used outside ctor or dtor, is the class code complete?

Comment: Won't you run into trouble with many different `unusedWinSockVar` if *this is all in a header*? Why does this have to be in a header #included by any file using `WinSock` if it only defines an unused variable? Shouldn't `unusedWinSockVar` be declared in a source file (contributing to the library)?

Comment: @didierc It is complete. There is only the ctor and dtor

Comment: @Walter Good question. It never occurred to me. Since this header also includes the winsock API header, I just included it to get the API. You are probably right.

Comment: @Walter I was thinking that he might be using some other static objects that use winsock in their constructors - then this would be the only way to make sure that winsock is initialized no matter what initialization sequencing of translation units is. Usually compilers should have better ways to achieve that (ie. construction priority in g++).

Comment: I agree this shouldn't be in a header file if it is used to execute the code in the constructor only once. It is probably implementation detail and should possibly go in the source file where main is to ensure it is not included in any other source file. That way, you do not need to protect the static variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think that `private: static int inst = 0;` is a valid construct, my compilers complains loudly - if you omitted that you have something like `int WinSock::inst = 0` in some .cpp file in your project for simplicity, then it's ok. If not and your project compiles at all, there is a good chance that all translation units will use a different variable, and therefore result in incorrect behavior.

Secondly, if any of the static-object constructors creates a new thread, then you need to make your code thread safe. From C++ standard p. 3.6.2:

> If a program starts a thread (30.3), the subsequent initialization of
>   a variable is unsequenced with respect to the initialization of a
>   variable defined in a different translation unit. Otherwise, the
>   initialization of a variable is indeterminately sequenced with respect
>   to the initialization of a variable defined in a different translation
>   unit.

Indeterminate sequencing means that initialization will not have any particular ordering, but it will not overlap, so you don't need any additional safeguards. No ordering means that constructors in different compilation unis might overlap, and therefore thread safety is required.

Thirdly, do you even need it done like this? Do you have other static objects that use winsock in their constructors? I really cannot think of any other reason to do it like that.

Comment: I need it to make sure winsock is only initialized nce, and is not cleaned up until everyone is done with it.

Comment: Then use one static object in one of your cpp files and it should do the trick - unless you have other static objects that use winsock in their constructors, that are spread among different compilation units. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

Given the specific scenario that you describe, this is fine without adding synchronization.

Your concern is that Winsock is initialized (and de-initialized) before (after) `main` runs, this is guaranteed to be the case. The code is guaranteed to be only called once from one thread, too. This (the fact that there's only one thread) makes synchronization useless.

Assuming that other static global objects use Winsock (whether or not they spawn threads), that would of course be unsafe, but it wouldn't be any safer with a mutex either. The initialization takes place at an implementation-defined point in time before `main`.
Therefore, no static global object can use Winsock in a safe, well-defined way using this construct, since either way you don't know whether initialization occurred first. Synchronizing it doesn't change a thing for that detail.

Note: the initialization of `inst` inside the class declaration isn't allowed as it is.

Comment: "the initialization of inst inside the class declaration is a C++11 feature" AFAIK no, this isn't allowed in C++11 either. [class.static.data]/3 "If a non-volatile const static data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a brace-or-equal-initializer [...]" It's allowed for `const` static data members, which has already been the case in C++03.

Comment: @DyP: You're right, it's allowed for non-static members only. Changed wording accordingly. (But it would be nicer to skip all that static stuff alltogether anyway, and just create a Winsock initializer object on the stack as the first thing in `main`.)

Comment: Ok, and what if there are some other static objects spread across compilation units that use winsock in their constructors? And what if there are static objects that start new threads in their constructors, before `main` function even starts?

Comment: "The initialization takes place at an implementation-defined point in time before main" - C++ standard requires that inside one compilation unit initialization is sequenced according to declaration order. My impression was that he wanted to have a static object of `WinSock` class in every compilation unit (assuming somewhere at the top), so that at least one of them was already initialized when needed. This of course requires synchronizing between objects in different compilation units.

Comment: @j_kubik: In that case (other static objects spread across CUs), it is unsafe, and there exists no way to make it safe (threads or no threads). It is true that C++ guarantees an order within a single compilation unit, but across different units (which is the case as stated in the Q) it is implementation defined. Having a static global in every compilation unit makes no sense, and initializing Winsock many times doesn't make sense either. The whole point of this construct (that looks somehow like a singleton) is that you do it only once.

Comment: The most elegant solution is really to scrap the singleton-like stuff (i.e. the inst counter) and just create an object on the stack as the first thing in `main`. This is none worse, but it works without globals and statics, and it makes the intent clear too.

Comment: @Damon That's my opinion too. But singletons are there to be used, so if somebody wants to, why not. "Having a static global in every compilation unit makes no sense, and initializing Winsock many times doesn't make sense either". He is not initializing winsock many times - he is having multiple object that are initializing it and one singleton-like `static int WinSock::inst;` that is a safeguard against multiple initialization.